# Average rating script

Tags: php, mysql, rating

I need to know how to make a rating script for a site. I have a form that submits a rating out of ten to **MySQL**. How would you get the average rating to be displayed from the **MySQL** column?

---using PHP with MySQL

Answer (score 2):

the best way is to store 2 columns - rate_count and rate_total. then when you get a new rating you just issue an update like this :

```
update rating_table set rate_count = rate_count + 1, rate_total = rate_total + $rating where id = $id
```

then to get the average you retrieve rate_count and rate_total. as long as rate_count is >0, rate_total/rate_count will give you your average rating.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post and code http://www.amitpatil.me/youtube-like-rating-script-jquery-php/